# How to build a table with devided dates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

would you please help me with my problem?

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 and I have a huge table with many, many employees.
In this table I have Data concerning "earnings", "beginn of contract" and "end of contract".
So what I want to build is: I want to get a resultset in which the time the employee worked for the company is devided into weeks and how much money he earned in avarage in every of week. Each week should start with the day of "beginn of contract" and the last row should be the last day of the week which ends with "end of contract".

For example:

`Employee Number | StartDate | EndDate | Salary
     4711            20150101    20150124    4000`

`Employee Number | Weeks |    AVG Salary (weeks)
    row1: 4711        20150101      800
     row2: 4711        20150108      800
     row3: 4711        20150115      800
     row4: 4711        20150122      800
     row5: 4711        20150124      800`

Please note, the 5th row ends with 20150124 not with the last day of the week.

So my code is until now is. But it is not finished, I dont know how to build the weeks in the logic I mentioned above:

```
  DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE
    (
      ID VARCHAR(50) ,
     Earning FLOAT,
      StartDate DATE ,
     EndDate DATE
    )INSERT  INTO @tbl
        ( ID, Earning, StartDate, EndDate
    SELECT  employee_ID  AS ID   
    ,([Total Earning]/ (SELECT datediff(WEEK,[EndDate],
    [StartDate])+1
    FROM [employee_table] WHERE employee_ID = 'EKA-0004562'))
    ,[StarTDate]
    ,[EndDate]
    FROM [employee_table]
    WHERE  employee_ID = 'EKA-0004562'
    ;
    WITH    cte
              AS ( SELECT   T.ID ,
                        T.Earning ,
                        T.StartDate ,
                        T.EndDatum ,
                        CONVERT(DATE, NULL) AS Dt ,
                        n = 0
               FROM     @tbl AS T
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   cte.ID ,
                        cte.Earning ,
                        cte.StartDate ,
                        cte.EndDatum ,
                        DATEADD(WEEK, n, cte.StartDate) ,
                        cte.n + 1
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    n <= DATEDIFF(WEEK, cte.StartDate, cte.EndDatum)
             )
    SELECT  cte.ID ,
            cte.Earning,
            dt AS WEEKS
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   cte.Dt IS NOT NULL
```

Can you please give me an advice how to build that?

Comment: there are 5 days between 20150101 and 20150107 and 6 days between 20150114 (or 21). Should it be 20150101, 20150108, 20150115, 20150122... ?

Comment: Yes Julien, you are right. My bad, I just edited it. Thanks

Comment: You might want to rethink your breakout. If start date was really Jan 01 then I see three whole weesk plus a partial week. I would have split that into four "weeks" and not five. Even counting by calendar weeks this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

- I first create dummy data:

  ```
  Declare @data table(Employee_Number int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime, Salary bigint)
  Insert into @data(Employee_Number, StartDate, EndDate, Salary) values
      (4711, '20150101', '20150124', 4000)
      , (4712, '20150101', '20150201', 4000);
  ;
  ```

Note that I added a second row. It will work with as many rows as you want.

- Main query

  ```
  with inc(n) as(
      Select 7*(ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 1)) -1)
      From (
          Select 1 From (values (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x1(n)
          Cross Join (values (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x2(n)
      ) x(n)
  )
  Select Employee_Number
      , Weeks = case when DATEADD(DAY, i.n, StartDate) <= EndDate then DATEADD(DAY, i.n, StartDate) else EndDate end
      , Avg = Salary/(CEILING(CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) as numeric(9,1))/7)+1)
  From @data d
  Inner Join inc i on i.n < ((DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate)))+7
  Order By Employee_Number, Weeks
  ```

`Inc` create a list of continous number from 0 to 700 (7*100) that will be added to StartDate. If you need a range of more than 7*100, add x3 (<7*1.000), x4 (<7*10.000) and so on.

- Output:

  ```
  Employee_Number Weeks                       Average
  4711            2015-01-01 00:00:00.000     800
  4711            2015-01-08 00:00:00.000     800
  4711            2015-01-15 00:00:00.000     800
  4711            2015-01-22 00:00:00.000     800
  4711            2015-01-24 00:00:00.000     800
  4712            2015-01-01 00:00:00.000     666
  4712            2015-01-08 00:00:00.000     666
  4712            2015-01-15 00:00:00.000     666
  4712            2015-01-22 00:00:00.000     666
  4712            2015-01-29 00:00:00.000     666
  4712            2015-02-01 00:00:00.000     666
  ```

Comment: Julien, thank you very much. That is exactly what I need. You helped me a lot. I am so happy that there is a community like this in which people like you help people like me : )

Comment: You should probably use `ceiling(days/7.0)`. I don't think that `2+` thing is reliable.

Comment: @shawnt00 it has been edited already. +2 and the whole line was incorrect indeed.

Comment: Well I think dividing by 7.0 accomplishes the same without the explicit cast. Either way. But doesn't the `ceiling()` take care of the "plus 1" problem?

Comment: Yes it does, But cast seems clearer since it is explicit in sample code. Do you think it is better to remove it and only use 7.0?

Comment: Most people probably don't know what's going on. Probably safe to be clear. So can start and end date be the same?

Comment: @shawnt00 is used because it needs to keep the last date, hence +1 week and the case, start and end can be the same, result would be 1 row with 4000 only.

Comment: So there is no need to use the ceiling function?

Comment: Maybe it is `days / 7 (integer divide) + 1)`. It was the adding two that caught my eye at first but now I think I'm wrong about using `ceiling()` unless I'm just mixed up about how the week counting works.

Comment: @shawnt00 Ceilling is necessery because it is a 23 day range, 23/7 = 3.28... Ceilling(3.28) = 4, +1 for the enddate = 5 rows

Comment: I looked up at the sample output and realized that it makes no sense to me. I would divide that into 3 whole weeks and 1 partial week rather than the 5 listed there. Am I missing something?

Comment: @shawnt00 I think you are right but this is what has been asked in the question

Comment: @Julien Yeah, I just remembered your `n` starts at zero. I guess your results has the right number of rows.